# How to draw an image into QR code with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

In my project I am trying to generate a QR code with an image in it based on stored blobs (1 Qr code + 1 logo) in my SQL table.

I have thw following code but can't seem to store the new image into my table. 
Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
//for connection
$sName = "localhost";
$sUser = "Username";
$sPass = "Password";
$sDb = "Database";
$Conn = new mysqli ($sName, $sUser, $sPass, $sDb);

//variables i pass from another app
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn, $_POST["PassEmail"]);
$qContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
$qOverlay = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES["overlay"]["tmp_name"]));

$Sql = "SELECT * FROM `userprofile_login` INNER JOIN `userprofile_personalprofile` ON userprofile_login.userid = userprofile_personalprofile.userid WHERE userprofile_login.email = '".$Email."' ";
$Result = mysqli_query($Conn, $Sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows ($Result) > 0) {
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($Result);

    $qCheckSql = "SELECT `userid` FROM `userprofile_qr` WHERE userid = '".$Row['userid']."' ";
    $qCheckResult = mysqli_query($Conn, $qCheckSql);

    $Row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qCheckResult);
    if (mysqli_num_rows ($qCheckResult) < 1) {
        //if there 0 result from previous query, insert new data
        $InsertSql = "INSERT INTO `userprofile_qr` (`userid`, `qrcode`, `overlay`)
                        VALUES ('".$Row['userid']."', '$qContent', '$qOverlay')";
        $InsertResult = mysqli_query($Conn, $InsertSql);
    } else {
        //is there ia a result from the previous query, update data
        $UpdateSql = "UPDATE `userprofile_qr` SET
                    `qrcode` = '$qContent',
                    `overlay` = '$qOverlay'
                    WHERE userid = '".$Row2['userid']."' ";
        $UpdateResult = mysqli_query($Conn, $UpdateSql);
    }
```

The first part works, the problem is the bottom part where I want to combine the QR code and the logo:

```
        $qSql = "SELECT `qrcode`, `overlay` FROM `userprofile_qr` WHERE userid = '".$Row2['userid']."' ";
        $qSelect = mysqli_query($Conn, $qSql);

        include 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
        $qRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qSelect);

        $tImage = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($qRow['qrcode'])."'/>";
        $tOverlay = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($qRow['overlay'])."'/>";

        header("Content-type: image/png");
        $aQr = imagecreatefromjpeg($tImage);
        $QrWidth = imagesx($aQr);
        $QrHeight = imagesy($aQr);

        $aOverlay = imagecreatefrompng($tOverlay);
        $OverlayWidth = imagesx($aOverlay);
        $OverlayHeight = imagesy($aOverlay);

        $OverlayQrWidth = $QrWidth / 3;
        $OverlayQrHeight = $OverlayHeight / ($OverlayWidth / $OverlayQrWidth);

        imagecopyresampled($aQr, $aOverlay, $OverlayQrWidth, $OverlayQrHeight, 0, 0, $OverlayQrWidth, $OverlayQrHeight, $OverlayWidth, $OverlayHeight);
        imagepng($aQr);

        $oImage = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($aQr)."'/>";

        $UpdateCombineSql = "UPDATE `userprofile_qr` SET
                        `combine` = '$oImage'
                        WHERE userid = '".$Row2['userid']."' ";
        $CombineResult = mysqli_query($Conn, $UpdateCombineSql);

        echo "Success";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual error? Also, my recommendation would be to only store the base64 encoded string, then when reading from the database, parse that into an img tag before displaying.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: And what debugging have you done? Are you checking for errors? What's with that `}` at the end? Where's the code that opens that? Where is `$Row2` defined?

Comment: Why are you saving QR codes to the database when you can always generate them in an instant on demand?

Comment: @rickjerrity  I pass the QR code and logo from another app to php. then in php I want to combine those 2 items. storing the images is just some sort of debugging for me to see there are actual output from php to mysql table. The problem is when trying to combine the qr code and logo there are no output to mysqli table

Comment: @Patrick Q This is just a part of the whole script, the first part is just some connection stuff and for storing the external Qr code and logo that I pass from another app. that part works. My problem is this second part I show you. This part is for combining the 2 items into 1.  Since i don't have any input in my sql table, i think there is no output from this part

Comment: @tadman  This script is basically for testing, since it's the first time I use php. storing the QR is just a way for me to know how to store images to mysql table.

Comment: The best way to store images in a database is to *not* store images in the database, that's the real lesson here. Binary data tends to massively bloat your database, slowing backups, making it slower to restore in the event of a disaster, and massively complicating the process of serving up the images. Files on disk or in an object store like Amazon S3 are almost always faster, simpler, and easier to deal with.

Comment: That being said, if you *do* need to store binary data in the database it's extra super important to use prepared statements to make sure the data's properly encoded. `addslashes` should not appear in your code, it's not a SQL escaping method.